# Express the equation as a first order System in the $(p,q)$ state-plane.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Express the equation as a first order System in the $(p,q)$ state-plane.

$$p'' + 5p' + \sin(p) = 2\sin(2t)$$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Set $q=p'$ and remove the first and reduce the second to first derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p'=q$.

Then the system becomes

$p' =q$

$q'+q + \sin(p) = 2\sin(2t)$